# How to share multiple javascript between different solutions

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a javascript file that I would like to share between multiple solutions.  I thought I might be able to add a link from the js file and put it into my project but in my aspx code it doesn't seem to find it.

```html
<script src="CoreScripts/Javascripts/SharedScripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

BTW this was asked before but it was never answered:
[How do I share common JS files between multiple solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033828/how-do-i-share-common-js-files-between-multiple-solutions)

Also I do not want to compile the javascript file into a dll.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just copy the .js file and move it into the new solution?

Comment: The problem with that is if someone changes something in that javascript file and doesn't copy all the changes to all the other solutions that use that javascript file.

Comment: @Erik Philips lays this out really well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540292/how-do-you-share-scripts-among-multiple-projects-in-one-solution

Comment: I have looked at that as well.  But that is using the same javascript in the same solution for multiple projects in that one solution.  I want to use the same javascript in multiple solutions.